# jqGrid cell in edit mode only for inline add

Tags: jqgrid, mvcjqgrid

How can I enable one column to be editable only if it's in a new row? This column must be read-only in existing rows when in edit mode.

The editable attribute works for new and existing rows.

Comment: there is a param to disable edit and only enable add. .jqGrid('inlineNav',pagerid, {edit:false, add:true})

Comment: The user will be able to edit, but only for some rows.

Answer (score 0):

What is the type of editing are you using? 
Form editing or inline editing?

If it is form editing you can use beforeShowForm event to hide the non-editable fields from the edit form.

```
beforeShowForm:function(formid)
{
 id="#tr_"+columnName(as given in column model);
 $(id, form).hide();
}
```

you need to make the hidden fields visible in add form again by using the same event

```
beforeShowForm:function(formid)
 {
  id="#tr_"+columnName(as given in column model);
  $(id, form).show();
 }
```

If it is inline editing before calling editRow, set editable flag to false

```
$('#gridId').jqGrid('setColProp',columnName,{editable: false});
```

and after editRow was over reset the editable flag to true to make editable for newly added rows

```
$('#gridId').jqGrid('setColProp',columnName,{editable: true});
```

Hope it helps....

Comment: I'm using inline editing, however, the user can edit and add new rows at the same time, then I can't disable the column editing for the entire grid.

Comment: Don't set editable flag in column model. Before Calling addRow method set $('#gridId').jqGrid('setColProp',columnName,{editable: true}); and before calling editRow method set $('#gridId').jqGrid('setColProp',columnName,{editable: false});

Comment: I do not save every row on every change, the user can change several (or all) and add a bunch of rows before submitting them. If I use setColProp, all of the rows will have that column editable or read only on these events.

Comment: So,is your problem to distinguish the add and edit operations.You can do it by adding a new element to rowdata. rowdata = ('#gridid').jqGrid ('getRowData',rowid); If it is add operation set rowdata.opflag = 'add'; or else set it to 'edit'. Read this flag before sending row into edit mode(onselectrow or ondoubleclick) and according to that flag set editable property of the corresponding columns either true or false.